# Energy of a system

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, elasticity

I'm considering a ring of mass $m$ sliding along a [cardioid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cardioid.html) with equation $r=a(1+\cos\theta)$. We let the angle between the downward vertical and the radius vector be $\theta$. The ring is attached to the origin by an elastic string with natural length $a$ and modulus $2kmg$ where $k$ is a positive constant (and $g$ is the common one).

I'm trying to write down the energy of the system but I can't get my head around it. Can you help me please?

Right now I'm guessing there's a potential energy that I would say is $mgh$ where $h=a(\cos\theta+1)\sin(\theta-\pi)=-a(\cos\theta+1)\cos\theta$ and the elastic one that I would say is $\frac{2kmg(extension)^2}{2a}$ where the extension is $a(\cos\theta+1)-a=a\cos\theta$. Is that right or am I completely mistaken?